# How to remove nested for loops while filling a matrix

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to fill a larger matrix (`A`) by using the entries of a smaller matrix (`B`), the relevant python code is

```
dim = N_Om * 2 * a

A = np.zeros(dim * dim, dtype="complex").reshape(dim, dim)  # Large matrix

for alpha in range(0, 2):
    for l in range(1, l_max + 1):
        B = get_B(l, alpha)  # small matrix of rank NOm

        for i in range(0, N_Om):
            for j in range(0, N_Om):

                A[
                    i * 2 * a
                    + alpha * a
                    + (l - 1) * (l + 1) : i * 2 * a
                    + (2 * l + 1)
                    + (l - 1) * (l + 1)
                    + alpha * a,
                    j * 2 * a
                    + alpha * a
                    + (l - 1) * (l + 1) : j * 2 * a
                    + (2 * l + 1)
                    + alpha * a
                    + (l - 1) * (l + 1),
                ] = B[i, j] * np.eye(
                    2 * l + 1
                )  # filling a diag mat for specific l and alpha
```

Unfortunately, the nested `for` loops with respect to `i` and `j` cause performance issues. Is it possible to replace these `for` loops with respect to `i` and `j` by some vectorized operation?

Comment: Hey Vishal! Could you provide input examples so the code was reproducible? And maybe some explanation as to what is it you are creating?

Comment: `alpha * a` can be computed higher and once, same `(l - 1) * (l + 1)`. To vectorize this you may want to create 2D array of indices, take a look at `np.meshgrid`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.